# Getting nil [transitionContext containerView] in Custom transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am trying to create custom animation during transition between two uiviewcontrollers. When i am trying to pop a view controller i am getting `nil` object in `[transitionContext containerView]` . Here is my code for custom transition class

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UIViewController * toViewController   = (UIViewController *)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *fromViewController = (UIViewController *)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];//returns nil
    [containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];
    [fromViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
}
```

I am using similar kind of code while pushing the view controller and its working perfectly. But during pop its creating trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this issue myself, and it looks like you need to add your `fromViewController`'s view to `containerView` as well.

As the documentation for the `transitionContext`'s `containerView` method says:

> The animator object is responsible for adding the view of the presented view controller...

It's unclear why, but not adding your `fromViewController`'s view (the "presented view controller" view) to the `containerView` results in a working transition the first time, but a `nil` `containerView` on subsequent transitions.

Comment: Isn't the "presented view controller" the toViewController?  This seems to suggest you don't add the fromViewController:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830258/container-view-disappearing-on-completetransition    ETA: I just noticed the original question is iOS7.  My comments is iOS8+ I believe, based on that link.